# Getting intellisense to pick up intermediate cs file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have an XSD file (a DTD) which I run the XSD tool on to produce a C# file. I have modified my csproj's msbuild file in the following two places:

Added a special type for the item group:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <SchemaFiles Include="Data\DeepZoomSchema.xsd">
   </SchemaFiles>
</ItemGroup>
```

And then at the bottom of the file:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Inputs="@(SchemaFiles)" Outputs="@(SchemaFiles->'$(IntermediateOutputPath)%(Filename).cs')">
  <XSD Language="CS" GenerateFromSchema="classes" SuppressStartupBanner="false" Namespace="DZParallelLib.Data" Sources="@(SchemaFiles)" AdditionalOptions="/out:$(IntermediateOutputPath)" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="@(SchemaFiles->'$(IntermediateOutputPath)%(Filename).cs')">
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

First of all, this project now compiles just fine. So I guess I have the hard part done. However, intellisense is broken in the sense that it never parses the DeepZoomSchema.cs output file.

In my ideal world, from the VS2012 IDE, I would like the .cs file to be found and parsed. I have found a way to do this, which is the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <SchemaFiles Include="Data\DeepZoomSchema.xsd">
  </SchemaFiles>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="@(SchemaFiles->'$(IntermediateOutputPath)%(Filename).cs')">
    <Visible>False</Visible>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

And then the build step becomes a lot more simple:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="XSD" AssemblyName="Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Inputs="@(SchemaFiles)" Outputs="@(SchemaFiles->'$(IntermediateOutputPath)%(Filename).cs')">
  <XSD Language="CS" GenerateFromSchema="classes" SuppressStartupBanner="false" Namespace="DZParallelLib.Data" Sources="@(SchemaFiles)" AdditionalOptions="/out:$(IntermediateOutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

Now things are correctly parsed by the IDE (and the solution still builds), but it feels wrong. When I've written MS build rules in the past (and I admit, I've not done very many) I've always put the intermediate output files inside the build rule (as I did earlier on). Also, it feels like I should be using the "DependentUpon" tag here, and making them visible, just not shown by default in the IDE (sort of like a code-behind file??). Basically, the first solution feels like it is the "proper" way, but the IDE doesn't like it.

So, my question: Is there a better way to get what I want done than this second solution I've described?

Comment: Marc - thanks for fixing my misspelling!